# Open sublime text file at a line number using command line

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to open a file using [sublime text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), and I would like to open it with the cursor at a concrete line number.

I've been checking `subl --help` but I could find no option for a concrete line. Therefore I'm just using:
`subl filename`

Is there any option to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `:line` to open at the given line:

```
subl file.txt:345
```

In my version of sublime-text 3, `subl --help` does give me the indication (last line):

```
subl --help
Sublime Text build 3143

Usage: sublime_text [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: sublime_text [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific location.
```